# When I ran the command "gh auth login" in gitbash , I get "You appear to be running in MinTTY without pseudo terminal support."

Tags: github-cli

Here is the bug in gitbash,thanks for your reply.

```
$ gh auth login
? What account do you want to log into?  [Use arrows to move, type to filter]
> GitHub.com
  GitHub Enterprise Server
could not prompt: Incorrect function.
You appear to be running in MinTTY without pseudo terminal support.
To learn about workarounds for this error, run:  gh help mintty
```

Answer (score 0):

YES! I solve the bug accidentally. Sometimes we don't need to figure out what the bug tips want us to do like this bug tips. 
Firstly,you should find where your github cli install.
Then，open the terminal in this directory.You can download github cli in [here](https://cli.github.com/).
Finally,you can find you can get want you want when you input `gh auth login`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).